# taking date input and grouping pandas datfarme as per time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have  a pandas dataframe with date and time values as follows.

```
    Date        Time      Pattern       
0   06/01/13    0:00:01     A
1   06/02/13    1:00:01     B
2   06/03/13    2:00:01     A
3   06/04/13    3:00:01     C
```

Now i intend to take date input from user as follows:

```
date = str(input('Input date in mm-dd-yy format'))
```

Now how should i find/group by all the rows with input date by user and copy it to a new dataframe. I tried many things but got confused with datatime conversion.

How should i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your `Date` column is `datetime`

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Then use `query`

```
date = pd.to_datetime(input('Input date in mm-dd-yyyy format'))
df.query('Date == @date')
```

[image]

---

***response to @learningprogramming***
You can include other criteria in `query`

```
date = pd.to_datetime(input('Input date in mm-dd-yyyy format: '))
df.query('Date == @date & Pattern == "B"')
```

[image]

---

***`loc` works as well***

```
date = pd.to_datetime(input('Input date in mm-dd-yyyy format: '))
df.loc[(df.Date == date) & (df.Pattern == 'B')]
```

[image]

---

***putting all in the inputs***

```
date = pd.to_datetime(input('Input date in mm-dd-yyyy format: '))
pattern = str(input('Input pattern type: '))
df.query('Date == @date & Pattern == @pattern')
```

[image]

Comment: i also intend to filter dataframe as per Pattern. I tried following: `df_compute = df.loc[(df['Pattern'] == input_pattern) & (df['Date'].values == date)]` and still getting invalid type comparison error.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column named 'Date' a string? If so, you can try something like:

`subset = df[df['Date'] == date]`

Comment: 'Date' column in dataframe is object.

Comment: Then follow the solution suggested by @piRSquared